# scope and integration tests with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I can not see my post lists if I have a scope in my `Post` model:

Model:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  ...
  scope :last_nine, where(:published.ne => nil).limit(9).order_by([:created_at, :desc])
end
```

Controller:

```
def index
 @posts = Post.last_nine.where(locale: locale)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Integration tests with capybara:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Posts" do
  let!(:posts) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:post, 3) }
  subject { page }
  describe "index page should have last nine results" do
    posts.each do |p|
      current_path.should == root_path
      should have_selector "h4 a", :text => post.title
    end
    save_and_open_page
  end
end
```

I can not see my last nine posts in capybara output with `save_and_open_page` method.

However if I remove `@posts = Post.last_nine.where(locale: locale)` and add `@posts = Post.all` in my controller:

```
def index
   @posts = Post.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

My test is working fine with `@posts = Post.all` and I can see my posts list in capybara output.

**How can I test with a model scope my integration test with capybara?**

Comment: are you sure the posts match the locale?

Comment: Thank you brother, the error was with locale :). Thanks!

Comment: @hyperrjas You should answer this question so that it won't appear in the "unanswered questions" section.